# HTML5 Validation - Easy Way to have real time validation?

Tags: html, validation

I am using HTML5 for user validation. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<input type="text" name="name"  id="usernametb" title="Minimum 8 Characters, only letters 
 and numbers" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,40}$" placeholder="Enter a Valid UserName" required />
```

I would like for user to get an error message either as soon as they type a username that doesnt match the validation pattern or when they tab to next field. Is there an easy way to do this with HTML5.

Right now, the error message doesn't display until I click "submit" and force a postback.

Comment: use javascript, e.g. `onkeyup="validateUsername(this.value)"` .

Answer (score 0):

This is a html5 validation plugin for jquery: http://ericleads.com/h5validate/ .

Quote from the plugin site:

> Best practice realtime HTML5 form validation for jQuery. Works on all popular browsers, including old ones like IE6.

If you want to use your own javascript, use something like:

```
onkeyup="validateUsername(this)"
```

…so for example:

```
<input type="text" name="name"  id="usernametb" title="Minimum 8 Characters, only letters  and numbers" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,40}$" placeholder="Enter a Valid UserName" onkeyup="validateUsername(this)" required />
```

Happy coding!

Comment: I was actually able to get real-time client side validation working with just HTML5 and CSS (working in modern browsers). Read this article for details: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/#.UeWC0o2G3-t

Comment: livevalidation.com is some sort of domain parked spam thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experiences with the parsley.js library:

http://parsleyjs.org/

Also for other input types (eg phone, email, URL) html5 can validate by itself, won't fix the example you have but it is very powerful and an insanely lightweight tool when it fits.

eg:

```
    <input type="tel" name="cellPhone"></input>
```

Good luck!